# Finding and storing groups of rows PK

Tags: postgresql

My problem is for Postgresql 10 but it probably is also relevant for other DB systems.

I have several tables in which I need to identify groups based on several criteria (some of them are PostGIS-geospatial criteria, some other are shared values in certain columns, ... that don't matter).

I am going to take a simple example. Let's say I have I have first table with people:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
desk_number varchar(20)
)
```

and that I want to group all employees that share the same desk (field *desk_number*).
Illustration :

```
employees
--------------
id | name | desk_number
1  | Bill | 314
2  | Joe  | 200
3  | Bob  | 314
4  | Matt | 189
5  | Sam  | 314
6  | Anne | 150
```

In this example, what I want to have is the list of employees sharing desk number 314 : Bill, Bob and Sam (id: 1, 3, 5).

My current query for finding this is :

```
WITH findpairs AS
(   -- part 1 of the query : selecting pairs
    SELECT s1.id AS id1, s2.id AS id2
    FROM employees AS s1 
    JOIN employees AS s2
    ON s1.desk_number = s2.desk_number
    WHERE s1.id < s2.id
)
-- part2 of the query : filtering
SELECT s1.id1
FROM findpairs AS s1
LEFT JOIN findpairs AS s2
ON s1.id1 = s2.id2
WHERE s2.id2 IS NULL
;
```

**Explanations :** 
In the first part of the query, I find all pairs of rows that for employees that share the same desk.

Without the WHERE clause, I would obtain as a result:

```
id1 | id2
 1  | 3
 3  | 1
 1  | 5
 5  | 1
 1  | 1
 2  | 2
 3  | 3
 4  | 4
 5  | 5
 6  | 6
```

The WHERE clause "s1.id < s2.id" prevents returning matches for a row with itself and makes sure that for two rows matching each other, only one row will be returned.

With this WHERE clause, what the part 1 of the query returns is :

```
id1 | id2
 1  | 3
 1  | 5
 3  | 5
```

I only two pairs of rows (1-3 and 1-5) to define the group I need ; the row 3-5 is unnecessary. That is why the second part of the query also does some filtering : because of the previous "s1.id < s2.id" clause, I know the lowest of the *id* values is only present in s1.id and never in s2.id. By using a LEFT JOIN, I can identify these rows from the set returned by part 1 and discard the other ones.

The final result returned is :

```
id1 | id2
 1  | 3
 1  | 5
```

And I can store this as such in a specific table :

```
CREATE TABLE matched_employees
(  id1 integer, id2 integer )
```

**Question 1 : is there a less tedious way to do this ?**
This takes a hell of a time to run on my server with my dataset.

**Question 2 : instead to store the result in a table with pairs ( *matched_employees* ). Is there a better way to store this information (and easily access it later) ?**

Comment: If you do not need pairs, you can obtain array of ids via `SELECT array_agg(id) FROM employees GROUP BY desk_number;` and store this array. Also you can make pairs from array by getting (1st element, n-th element) pairs for n >= 2.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНоздрев Write that up as an answer! It answers both questions in one fell swoop. NB Add `order by` inside the `array_agg` so that the result is determinate.

Comment: Ok, then, this works when the JOIN clause is a simple equality. What about when it's more complex, such as when it is using a PostGIS function ? And another issue : how do I not keep the rows that don't match others ?

Comment: It should work, as long as you can put something in the `group by` clause that matches for rows that should be grouped together. You can add `having count(*) > 1` to the end of the query to keep only rows that match others.

Comment: The limit will be that GROUP BY is based on having values that can be compared. You can do GROUP BY (field_name) or GROUP BY (whatever formula that returns a numeric or string value), but you cannot do GROUP BY with a test that returns TRUE or FALSE. 
For example, with PostGIS, if you wanna group vector geometries that intersect each other, you will use the function ST_Intersect(geometry_field1, geometry_field2) that returns a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need real "pairs" you can get the list of employees sharing a desk using this:

```
select e1.*
from employees e1
where exists (select *
              from employees e2
              where e1.desk_number = e2.desk_number
                and e1.id <> e2.id);
```

If you want that as a single "list of IDs" you can use string_agg()

```
select string_agg(e1.id::text, ',') as id_list
from employees e1
where exists (select *
              from employees e2
              where e1.desk_number = e2.desk_number
                and e1.id <> e2.id);
```

Or use `array_agg()` to get those IDs as an array

Online example: http://rextester.com/AXVGA22292

Comment: Interesting. But your example has a flaw (compared to what I want) : 
It returns all rows without matching them together.

Comment: @DarthKangooroo: that's why I wrote "If you don't need real pairs".

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, based on comments from Colin 't Hart and Евгений Ноздрев

If the criterion for grouping rows is a field or a formula that will return a field-like value (numeric, text), it is possible to use array_agg :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT desk_number, array_agg (id) AS liste_ids FROM employees
    GROUP BY desk_number
) AS groups
WHERE array_length (liste_ids,1)>1
```

Or :

```
SELECT desk_number, array_agg (id) AS liste_ids FROM employees
GROUP BY desk_number
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Limitations :

- Does not work for grouping rows based on a boolean test (like PostGIS ST_Intersect or ST_DWithin functions).
- Does not select one of the items as being the 'master' row and the others duplicate like the code I originally proposed does.